# Google Maps Engine and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to use your own map created with Google Maps Engine with OpenLayers? Any examples?

Comment: one example http://slip-future.appspot.com/code-samples/examples/wms/openlayers2.html

Comment: another example http://slip-future.appspot.com/code-samples/examples/wms/openlayers2-swipe.html

Comment: I mean using 'My Maps' functionality of Google through WMS. I'm not sure if those examples do that. At least the URL's look different.

Comment: The link I get with 'Share' button looks like this: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zEPyhvV2JuZs.kxsndevFjZk4